# What a StoredProcedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is a stored procedure (at least I have to be assuming so), that constructs an Sql query as a String and then calls it with exec. For some reason the dude that called himself a programmer, concatenates some values using "~" characters and them splits them back in the application layer. This SP breaks when, some checkbox is "selected" .. The question is how can I debug this nightmare. I have found that when the CheckBox is selected, it adds an unnecessary "~1" to the beginning of some TypeCode and it breaks. if not selected, it works as intended. (BTW I'd really like to know what kind of coding practice is this thing called).

```
  ALTER  PROC [dbo].[BUTCEREP] @SirketKod varchar(10), @IlkTarih varchar(10), @SonTarih varchar(10), @Tip int, @Tur int, @MasrafMrk varchar(100), @DovizKod varchar(5), @MaliTKod varchar(10)
    -- Tip 0-TarihAraligi; 1-2AylikButce; 2-YTDButce; 3-YTDCompPrev
    -- Tur 0-Muhasebe 1-Gider 2-Butce 3-ButceMuhasebe 4-ButceGider
    AS
      declare
        @SqlText nvarchar(4000),
        @SqlBud varchar(4000),
        @SqlMuh varchar(4000),
        @SqlGid varchar(4000),
        @xIlkT datetime,
        @xSonT datetime,
        @ThisMonth varchar(10),
        @NextMonth varchar(10),
        @ThisYear varchar(10),
        @PrevYear varchar(10)


      if (not @IlkTarih is null) set @xIlkT = CONVERT(datetime,@IlkTarih,103)
      if (not @SonTarih is null) set @xSonT = CONVERT(datetime,@SonTarih,103)
      set @DovizKod=IsNull(@DovizKod, '')
      if @Tip=1 and MONTH(@xIlkT)=12 set @xIlkT = dateadd(month,-1,@xIlkT)

      set @ThisMonth = CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(@xIlkT))
      set @NextMonth = CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(@xIlkT)+1)
      set @ThisYear  = CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(@xIlkT))
      set @PrevYear  = CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(@xIlkT)-1)

      set @SqlMuh='select X.MuhHesapKod,X.Tarih,SUM(CAST(X.Borc   AS FLOAT)) Borc,'+
                                               'SUM(CAST(X.Alacak AS FLOAT)) Alacak' +
                   ' from (select CASE S.N WHEN 1 THEN LEFT(D.MuhHesapKod,3)' +
                                         ' WHEN 2 THEN LEFT(D.MuhHesapKod,7)' +
                                         ' ELSE D.MuhHesapKod END MuhHesapKod,' +
                                 'D.Tarih,Borc,Alacak' +
                  ' from '+@DovizKod+'MUH_D D inner join '+@DovizKod+'MUH_H H on (H.SirketKod=D.SirketKod) and (H.KontrolNo=D.KontrolNo)'+
                 ' CROSS JOIN dbo.SeriTable(3) S' +
                 ' where D.SirketKod=' + QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +
                  case when IsNull(@MasrafMrk,'')<>'' then ' and D.MasrafMrkKod in (select Kod from GetArray('+QuoteName(@MasrafMrk,'''')+'))' else '' end +
                  case @Tip
                    when 0 then ' and D.Tarih BETWEEN ' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xIlkT,103),''''),'D.Tarih') + ' and ' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xSonT,103),''''),'D.Tarih')
                    when 1 then ' and YEAR(D.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' and MONTH(D.Tarih) in ('+@ThisMonth+','+@NextMonth+')'
                    when 2 then ' and YEAR(D.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' and MONTH(D.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth
                    when 3 then ' and (YEAR(D.Tarih)='+@PrevYear+' or (YEAR(D.Tarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(D.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+'))'
                  end +
                  ' and IsNull(H.FisTip,'''')<>''KAPANIS'''+
                           ') X' +
                 ' where X.MuhHesapKod in (select Kod from MALIT_M where SirketKod=' + QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +
                                                                   ' and MaliTKod='  + QuoteName(@MaliTKod,'''') + ')' +
                 ' group by X.MuhHesapKod,X.Tarih'

      set @SqlMuh = ' select 1 Tip,CAST(4 AS char(1))+''~0~''+M.MuhHesapKod Kod,' +
                    case @Tip
                      when 0 then 'SUM((M.Borc-M.Alacak)) TopBak'
                      when 1 then 'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(M.Tarih)=' +@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(M.Tarih)=' +@NextMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A2Bak'
                      when 2 then 'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(M.Tarih)=' +@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(M.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A2Bak'
                      when 3 then 'SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(M.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' AND MONTH(M.Tarih)=' +@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(M.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' AND MONTH(M.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A2Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(M.Tarih)=' +@PrevYear+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(M.Borc-M.Alacak)) A3Bak'
                    end +
                    ' from (' + @SqlMuh + ') M' +
                    ' where M.MuhHesapKod in (select Kod from MALIT_M where SirketKod=' + QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +
                                                                       ' and MaliTKod=' + QuoteName(@MaliTKod,'''') + ')'+
                    ' group by M.MuhHesapKod'

      set @SqlGid = ' select 1 Tip,CAST(2 AS char(1))+''~0~''+C.GiderKod Kod,' +
                    case @Tip
                      when 0 then 'SUM((2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+') TopBak'
                      when 1 then 'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(C.Tarih)='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+') A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(C.Tarih)='+@NextMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+') A2Bak'
                      when 2 then 'SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(C.Tarih)=' +@ThisMonth+ ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+' AS FLOAT)) A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN MONTH(C.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+ ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+' AS FLOAT)) A2Bak'
                      when 3 then 'SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN YEAR(C.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' AND MONTH(C.Tarih)=' +@ThisMonth+ ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+' AS FLOAT)) A1Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN YEAR(C.Tarih)=' +@ThisYear+' AND MONTH(C.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+ ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+' AS FLOAT)) A2Bak,' +
                                  'SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN YEAR(C.Tarih)=' +@PrevYear+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*C.IslemTuru-1)*'+CASE WHEN @DovizKod='' THEN '(TutarTL+GVergiTutar)' ELSE 'GEURO' END+' AS FLOAT)) A3Bak'
                    end +
                    ' from CHI_D C'+
                    ' where C.GiderKod in (select Kod from MALIT_M where SirketKod=' + QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +
                                                                   ' and MaliTKod='  + QuoteName(@MaliTKod ,'''') + ')'+
                    case when IsNull(@MasrafMrk,'')<>'' then ' and C.MasrafMrkKod in (select Kod from GetArray('+QuoteName(@MasrafMrk,'''')+'))' else '' end +

                    case @Tip
                      when 0 then ' and C.Tarih BETWEEN ' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xIlkT,103),''''),'C.Tarih') + ' and ' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xSonT,103),''''),'C.Tarih') + ')'
                      when 1 then ' and YEAR(C.Tarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(C.Tarih) in (' +@ThisMonth+','+@NextMonth+')'
                      when 2 then ' and YEAR(C.Tarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(C.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth
                      when 3 then ' and (YEAR(C.Tarih)='+@PrevYear+' or (YEAR(C.Tarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(C.Tarih)<='+@ThisMonth+'))'
                    end +
                    ' group by C.GiderKod'

      set @SqlBud='select 0 Tip,CAST(D.IslemTipi AS char(1))+''~0~''+D.KalemKod Kod,' +
                  case @Tip
                    when 0 then 'sum((2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) TopBak'
                    when 1 then 'sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(D.BasTarih)='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A1Bak,' +
                                'sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(D.BasTarih)='+@NextMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A2Bak'
                    when 2 then 'sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(D.BasTarih)='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A1Bak,' +
                                'sum((2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A2Bak'
                    when 3 then 'sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(D.BasTarih)=' +@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A1Bak,' +
                                'sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(D.BasTarih)<='+@ThisMonth+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END*(2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A2Bak,' +
                                'sum((2*D.IslemTuru-1)*IsNull(D.Tutar,0)) A3Bak'
                  end +
                  ' from dbo.GetButceList('+ QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +','+ IsNull(QuoteName(@MasrafMrk,''''),'null')+','+QuoteName(@DovizKod,'''')+',0) D' +
                  ' where D.KalemKod in (select Kod from MALIT_M where SirketKod=' + QuoteName(@SirketKod,'''') +
                                                                 ' and MaliTKod='  + QuoteName(@MaliTKod,'''') + ')'+
                  case @Tip
                    when 0 then ' and D.BasTarih>=' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xIlkT,103),''''),'D.BasTarih') + ' and D.BitTarih<=' + IsNull(QuoteName(CONVERT(varchar,@xSonT,103),''''),'D.BitTarih')
                    when 1 then ' and YEAR(D.BasTarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(D.BasTarih) in (' +@ThisMonth+','+@NextMonth+')'
                    when 2 then ' and YEAR(D.BasTarih)='+@ThisYear+' and MONTH(D.BasTarih)<='+@ThisMonth
                    when 3 then ' and YEAR(D.BasTarih)='+@ThisYear
                  end +
                  ' group by D.KalemKod,D.IslemTipi'

    -- Tur 0-Muhasebe 1-Gider 2-Butce 3-ButceMuhasebe 4-ButceGider
      set @SqlText = case @Tur
                       when 0 then @SqlMuh
                       when 1 then @SqlGid
                       when 2 then @SqlBud
                       when 3 then @SqlBud + ' union all ' + @SqlMuh
                       when 4 then @SqlBud + ' union all ' + @SqlGid
                     end

      if @Tip in (1,2)
        set @SqlText='select Kod,' +
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 0 THEN IsNull(A1Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A10Bak,' +  --budget first
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 0 THEN IsNull(A2Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A20Bak,' +  --budget second
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 1 THEN IsNull(A1Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A11Bak,' +  --actual first
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 1 THEN IsNull(A2Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A21Bak ' +  --actual second
                      'from (' + @SqlText + ') X' +
                      ' group by Kod'
      else if @Tip = 3
        set @SqlText='select Kod,' +
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 1 THEN IsNull(A3Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A00Bak,' +  --actual prev
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 0 THEN IsNull(A1Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A10Bak,' +  --budget first
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 0 THEN IsNull(A2Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A20Bak,' +  --budget second
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 1 THEN IsNull(A1Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A11Bak,' +  --actual first
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 1 THEN IsNull(A2Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A21Bak,' +  --actual second
                            'SUM(CASE Tip WHEN 0 THEN IsNull(A3Bak,0) ELSE 0 END) A01Bak ' +  --budget yearly
                      'from (' + @SqlText + ') X' +
                      ' group by Kod'

      PRINT @SqlText
      exec sp_executesql @SqlText
```

Comment: "The question is how can I debug this nightmare." - Like everybody else would do it. Go through the code line by line, find out what it does, test it with different parameters, try to extrapolate the business rule and write a bug fix or a replacement if you dare.

Comment: If the question is how can I debug this nightmare, why is the title "What a StoredProcedure"?

Answer (score 2):

you should try rewriting this using CLR stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting would be the best solution.  But, to try and debug it, use SQL Profiler (one of the SQL Server performance tools that comes with SQL Server) to put a stored procedure trace on the database and capture the exact command that executes this stored procedure.  This will allow you to capture the exact parameter values being passed in and allow you to run it repeatedly in a SQL Management Studio window.

Then, you can modify the stored procedure to print out various values you wish to inspect at various points throughout the stored procedure in order to determine what is happening at any given point.

Alternatively, you can use visual studio to enable SQL debugging and actually step through the stored procedure.

Comment: Visual Studio SQL debugging works on SQL Server 2008 and higher.

Comment: I thought it was SQL 2005 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

1) at the top of the procedure, add an INSERT statement to log the input parameters into a table, with something like:

```
INSERT INTO YourLog (TextValue) VALUES ('EXEC BUTCEREP @SirketKod='''+COALESCE(@SirketKod,'NULL')+''', @IlkTarih='''+COALESCE(@IlkTarih,'NULL')+''', ...)
```

2) run this procedure several times from the application to capture the input parameters, including several good runs as well as the know problem.

3) add many PRINT statements all over the code.  Even break down the long assignments into smaller, yet multiple assignments (where different parts are concatenated, the "+") and put prints between them:

```
...
PRINT @SqlMuh
...
PRINT @SqlMuh
...
PRINT @SqlGid
...
```

4) take the 'EXEC ...' strings from the log, and run the commands from SSMS, look at the print output and the code and determine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how you could potentially debug this:

Change the beginning from this:

```
  ALTER  PROC [dbo].[BUTCEREP] @SirketKod varchar(10), @IlkTarih varchar(10), @SonTarih varchar(10), @Tip int, @Tur int, @MasrafMrk varchar(100), @DovizKod varchar(5), @MaliTKod varchar(10)
    -- Tip 0-TarihAraligi; 1-2AylikButce; 2-YTDButce; 3-YTDCompPrev
    -- Tur 0-Muhasebe 1-Gider 2-Butce 3-ButceMuhasebe 4-ButceGider
    AS
      declare
        @SqlText nvarchar(4000),
        @SqlBud varchar(4000),
        @SqlMuh varchar(4000),
        @SqlGid varchar(4000),
        @xIlkT datetime,
        @xSonT datetime,
        @ThisMonth varchar(10),
        @NextMonth varchar(10),
        @ThisYear varchar(10),
        @PrevYear varchar(10)
```

Into this:

```
  declare @SqlText as nvarchar(4000)
  declare @SqlBud as varchar(4000)
  declare @SqlMuh as varchar(4000)
  declare @SqlGid as varchar(4000)
  declare @xIlkT as datetime
  declare @xSonT as datetime
  declare @ThisMonth as varchar(10)
  declare @NextMonth as varchar(10)
  declare @ThisYear as varchar(10)
  declare @PrevYear as varchar(10)

  set @ThisYear = 'your test value'
  set @NextMonth = 'your test value'
  set @ThisMonth = 'your test value'
  set @SqlText = 'your test value'
  set @SqlBud = 'your test value'
  set @SqlMuh = 'your test value'
  set @SqlGid = 'your test value'
  set @xIlkT = 'your test value'
  set @xSonT = 'your test value'
  set @PrevYear = 'your test value'
```

And debug at will. Append select statements in between sections like:

```
select @SqlMuh
```

To know their values at specific places.

Once you're happy with the changes you've done, go back and ALTER the SP. This will cut down the repetitive task of ALTERING-EXECUTING everytime you want to check something.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project like this last year and I found that the best thing to do was to create a table with a identity field and a varchar field and write the @SqlText variable to it just before you EXEC it.  That way as you test and see results, you can get the latest SQL that was executed.

Long term, I agree with the majority of the people here that you should re-write this (although that's probably not a good short term solution unless this is the only SP that is like this).

Comment: everything is like this .. plus the deplhi code (which i am not a delphi programmer) ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamic SQL you really need to look at the Profile as has been stated before but using the PRINT command at the bottom will show you what is actually being sent so that you can debug. You will not get very far trying to debug it by looking at this code if you are not a SQL programmer. You need to print it out and then copy the Printed SQL to a new window and debug that code.

To be clear I am talking about the 2nd to last line of the Procedure
    `PRINT @SqlText`

The other tips here are good and at this point you just need to feed it different values (I would think from the app layer or using the declare statements mentioned) and find all the cases. I find it helpful when debugging business logic to make a flow chart or diagram of different parameters as a visual aide. Work through the procedure by commenting out lines of the join to understand the key relationships. I would say the hardest part will be all the date conversions - there is also a lot of repetitive code which should be placed into functions for improved readability.

With the delimiter ('~') it is likely used later on to parse the data somehow so I might also look into the other layers of the application, it could be the bug does not even exist here but is in a change made at the page level on loading.

As you work through it be sure to comment so that someone coming after you doesn't have to start from scratch!